# VS CodeのJava拡張機能が表示するエラー（The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files）を解決したい

Tags: java, ubuntu, vscode

Ubuntu 20.04上のVS CodeのExtension Pack for Javaで単純なJavaコード（`HelloWorld.java`）を書いているのですが、実行する前に拡張機能がエラーを表示しており、またコンパイルもできないのでこれを解決したいです。
ターミナル上では`javac HelloWorld.java`と`java HelloWorld`でコンパイル・実行できています。

JDKはHomebrewでOpen JDK 17をインストールしました。VS Codeの`setttings.json`にJDKのパスも設定してあります。

```
"java.home": "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.1"
```

コード及びVS Codeに表示されているエラーは以下の通りです。

## コード

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

## エラー

### VS Code上に勝手に表示されるエラー

```
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

```
The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

```
Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

```
String cannot be resolved to a type
```

```
System cannot be resolved
```

### VS Code上で実行しようとすると表示されるエラー

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project
```

## 環境

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Java: Open JDK 17
VS Code: Version 1.62.2, Snapからのインストール
VS Code拡張機能: Extension Pack for Java v0.18.6

## その他

JREはJDKと一緒にインストールされると聞いたので別途インストールはしていないです。
JDKインストール時のコマンドは

```
brew install openjdk
```

です。

質問に不備があれば訂正・加筆いたしますのでお知らせいただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: コマンドパレットのメニュー "**Java: Configure Java Runtime**" を選択して開かれるウィンドウの "**Installed JDKs**" タブにある "**Detected JDKs**" にセットアップしたJDKが表示されているでしょうか。(表示されている場合、)  "**Porject JDKs**" タブを開き、そのJDKがプロジェクトで利用されているでしょうか。[参考](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_settings-for-the-jdk)

Comment: @DEWAKazuyuki-出羽和之 　Detected JDKsのところは検出中のくるくるマークが回ったままでJDKが表示されないです。Project JDKsのところも設定されていないです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現状、 Homebrew でインストールした JDK (openjdk) を `java.home` に設定しても認識されないようです。
いずれも報告者は Mac ユーザのようですが、次の issue がありました:

- [OpenJDK 16 in java.home not recognized #1969](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1969)  - redhat-developer/vscode-java
- ["java.home" does not work on macOS with one than one JDK installed #339](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/339) - microsoft/vscode-java-pack

---

次のいずれかで回避できるようです:

- 環境変数 `JAVA_HOME` に Homebrew でインストールした openjdk を設定して VSCode を起動する([参考](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java#java-tooling-jdk))

  - 例えば `~/.bashrc` に `export JAVA_HOME=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.1/libexec` を追記する
  - この場合、 VSCode の `java.home` 設定は削除します。
- Homebrew 以外で JDK をインストールする

  - 例えば https://sdkman.io/ を利用する
  - この場合、 VSCode の `java.home` は新しくインストールしたパスを指定します(ただし例示した SDKMAN! では `JAVA_HOME` 環境変数が自動で設定されるので、単に `java.home` 設定を削除するだけでも良いです)。

いずれにせよ、 `java.home` 設定が Homebrew でインストールした openjdk を指したままになっていると問題が解消されないので注意してください。

VSCode から認識されれば、コマンドパレットのメニュー "**Java: Configure Java Runtime**" を選択して開かれるウィンドウの "**Installed JDKs**" タブにある "**Detected JDKs**" にセットアップしたJDKが表示されます。

Comment: 上記環境変数の設定で"Java: Configure Java Runtime" の"Detected JDKs" にJDKが表示されるようになりました。ありがとうございます！しかしエラーメッセージは変わらず表示されたままでした…

Comment: @asiangeorge VSCodeの `java.home` 設定が残ったままだとそのような事象になるのを確認しました。 `java.home`  設定が質問当時のままなら、削除した上で再度試してみてください。

Comment: java.home 設定を消すとエラーメッセージが消え、コンパイルできました。ありがとうございます！